# Nissan Rogue 2010 AWD clicking noise when turning

Tags: troubleshooting, drivetrain, awd

Have a high-mileage 2010 Rogue AWD that makes a clicking noise from the rear when rounding corners.

I suspect it was because it was improperly towed.

My web searches have led me to believe that it's either the CV joints/axle or the differential.

Is there an easy way to distinguish the two without disassembling anything?

I'll attempt to replace the rear axle myself if that's the issue. If it's the differential, I'll just scrap the vehicle.

Comment: I'd say cv joint. If you're differential was damaged you'd more likely get a grinding or whining noise and not just when turning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you resolved the issue, but most likely it is cv joint. You can get under car hold both inner and outer axle and shake them. If you hear any clicking/clacking sounds and feel movement your joint is bad.  Other way to test is to turn the wheel all the way to left/right( do it for both directions to check both cv joints (left and right) ) and drive in reverse if you hear clicking its the cv joint most likely.